# ObjectOutputStream need response from server?

Tags: java, sockets

```
Socket Client = new Socket("ip", port);
private ObjectOutputStream out;
out = new ObjectOutputStream(Client.getOutputStream());//line3
out.flush();
```

i have a socket program.when i have a client there is no problem.but when  client is more that one in second and later client the program  is `waiting` on line 3.it has no error and exception.what is problem?

```
        TCP = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
           if ("TCP".equals(Protocol)) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            RunServer();

        }   
            }
        });
        TCPWait = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    WaitForConnection();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
        TCPWait.start();
        TCP.start();
    public void RunServer() {
        try {

            while (true) {
                {
                    accessLock.lock();
                    if(CanContinue == false)
                        condition.await();
                    try {
//                        WaitForConnection();
                        GetStreams();
                        ProcessConnection();
                    accessLock.unlock();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "ارتباط قطع شد" + e.getMessage());


                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, e.getMessage());
        }
    public void WaitForConnection() throws IOException {
        jTextArea1.append("لطفا تا برقرای ارتباط صبر کنید.../n ");
        accessLock.lock();
        connection = server.accept();
       CanContinue = true;
       condition.signal();
       accessLock.unlock();

        jTextArea1.append("ارتباط از " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName() + "\n");

    }

    public void GetStreams() {
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket();
            s = connection;
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            out.flush();

            in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            jTextArea1.append("در حال برقرای ارتباط...\n");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "مشکل در برقرای ارتباط!\n");

        }

    }

    public void ProcessConnection() {
        SendData("ارتباط برقرا شد\n");
        try {
            jTextArea1.append((String) in.readObject() + "\n");

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        String message = "";

        do {
            try {

                jTextArea1.append((String) in.readObject() + "\n");
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        } while (message != "Exit");


    }
```

`WaitForConnection()` is a listener that is in thread and `runserver()` send and receive messages that is in another thread.

Comment: The clients are different java processes?

Comment: yes client is a program and server another one.

Comment: And you are starting multiple client programs when this problem happens?

Comment: Sounds like your server code isn't multi-threaded.  Can you show us that part?

Comment: Can you post the code on the server side?

Comment: Why is your `WaitForConnection` method call commented?

Comment: this method is listened to connection from client(this is in deitel book)java how to program 6th edition Sion 24

Comment: i call that both of them in runserver() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, you are only waiting for a connection once in this thread:

```
    TCPWait = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                WaitForConnection();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
```

instead of waiting for multiple connections in the main loop:

```
        while (true) {
            {
                accessLock.lock();
                if(CanContinue == false)
                    condition.await();
                try {
        //            WaitForConnection();
                    GetStreams();
                    ProcessConnection();
                accessLock.unlock();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "ارتباط قطع شد" + e.getMessage());


                }
            }
        }
```

So one client connects and then the rest are stuck, because you are never calling accept again. You should uncomment that call to `WaitForConnection();`

Comment: i wrote that but isn't correct.in processConecton() we have a loop see that

Comment: That loop only appends some text. The problem is that you are only calling accept once, so only one client can ever connect. Put a counter in your `WaitForConnection` method and see how many times it gets executed.

Comment: yes your right the accept is execute once.i put it in while(true) but it execute once!

Comment: Can you please update the original question with the code you have now?

Comment: the problem was in my thread that accept called one i solved that thanks.:)

Answer (score 1):

```
Socket s = new Socket();
s = connection;
```

Something seriously wrong there.

Comment: That's not really a problem. He's just allocating that socket for no reason, and then assigning it a socket obtained from `accept`. The real problem is that he's only calling `accept` once.